# Regex for Decimals

Tags: jquery, regex, html

I have a simple expression that I need to write, but I'm really not that great with regex.

My limits are: **maximum 1 digit . maximum 4 digits, allowing less**

These should pass.

```
1
1.2
1.23
1.234
1.2345
```

These should fail.

```
10
10.1
1.23456
```

The closest I've come is `\d\.\d{0,4}`, but it doesn't select 1, and selects the `0.1` and `1.2345` from the second list.

I should also specify that this is a check being done as the user types, if that makes a difference.

**Edit**

Since there are so many responses that cover several different points, I feel I should specify some more, especially because someone might point me down a better path. I am using this on a web form. It needs to only allow these conditions as the user types, so if they have "4" and try to enter "1" it won't allow it, but will if they enter "." first. Or will not allow input after they do something like "2.5345", since that's 4 digits after the decimal.

Comment: I have what I tried in the question.

Comment: If you set length with regex, you must use anchors. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/bI9qZ7/1).

Comment: @stribizhev the `0.1` is from the `10.1` in the fail list, meaning it accepts part of the wrong input.

Comment: Would `1.` be OK, or do you require it to be `1.0`?

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Does it allow look-behinds?

Comment: You might need two regexps: 1) for live validation `^\d(?:\.\d{0,4})?$` and 2) for final validation `^\d(?:\.\d{1,4})?$`.

Comment: You say "1 before the point, 4 after, maximum, allowing less". That implies `.2` should be allowed. If so, all four answers so far will fail because they mandate one starting digit, not one or less starting digits...

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, 1 before the point means that there has to be one digit before the decimal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^\d(\.\d{0,4})?$/
```

RegEx breakdown

`/` - Indicates the start of a Regular Expression

`^\d` - The expression starts with a digit

`\.` - Periods need to be escaped because otherwise they match any character.

`\d{0,4}` - Will match between 0 and 4 digits.

`()` - Captures everything enclosed

`?` - Matches 0 or 1 of an expression

Comment: This doesn't work for the case where it's just a single digit. This should work: 

    /^\d(\.\d{0,4})?$/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the parentheses to capture a group. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Answer went to you for breaking it all down.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d(\.\d{0,4})?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iE5gP5/2)

`(\.\d{0,4})?` makes part after decimal optional to allow for single digits as valid input.

**Caveat:** This will also allow `9.` as valid input.

Comment: The OP mentioned that this will be used as the user types. If he's using it as a mask, then the user will never be able to type the decimal with your regex because it requires a following digit. You may need to allow 0 to 4 instead.

Comment: Making it `\d{0,4}` will validate even `9.`, not sure if OP wants that.

Comment: As the user types `9.4`, it needs to validate each incremental step: `9`, `9.`, and `9.4`

Answer (score 1):

Try this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/aA7dB2/1)

```
^\d$|^\d\.\d{1,4}$
```

Comment: You can improve your regex by doing `^(\d|\d\.\d{1,4})$` to avoid repeating anchors, and you can use `^(?:` if you don't want to capture content

Comment: Note that alternations work slower than optional groups.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you also allowed without dot so you need: `^\d(\.\d{0,4})?$`